# Seamless integration between WordPress and BBpress

Tags: customization, bbpress

I have a WordPress site at domain.com and a BBPress install at domain.com/subfolder
the wp site has a menu item that goes to the forums, and I'd like the header to be the same between the two, so that they can navigate back to the main site.
how can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no easy way to do that. The only way I've seen so far is customizing WP and BBPress themes to match. For example http://themehybrid.com/ (WordPress) and http://themehybrid.com/support/ (BBPress).

Comment: how do you change the HTML in bbPress?

Comment: Not my area, but I think it uses themes in similar way to WP. Documentation is always good place to start [Themes and Templates](http://bbpress.org/documentation/themes/).

Answer (score 1):

Matt agrees that it is important (see [here](http://bbpress.org/blog/2010/07/wordpress-integration/)).

From a rumor I've heard, there is a plan to release bbpress as a WordPress plugin.

I would wait the fence on this one until it is done.

Comment: There is already [placeholder for plugin version](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bbpress/), but I have not seen even remote estimates on release. I know there are also talks about possibility of [BBPress merge with Justin Tadlock's forum plugin](http://themehybrid.com/support/topic/excited-for-launch#post-46714) (in development). Too many things undecided = it can be a long wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do so - http://www.wpwebhost.com/make-bbpress-theme-match-with-wordpress-by-deep-integration/

Answer (score 0):

Deep integration would make your server load increase enormously.So it is better to create a custom theme for bbpress.If you are new to this then just copy an existing theme into my-templates folder,rename the folder you have copied and do the modification in css and from their customize according to your need.The easiest would be to first include your active wordpress theme in bbpress header and fine tune from their.

Comment: why would integration increase server load?